# SQL Group by using the First N elements in each group

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, group-by, average

Suppose I have the next table:

```
+------------+---------+
|    MovieId |  rating  |
+------------+---------+
|      1     |     4   |
|      1     |     3   |
|      1     |     2   |
|      1     |     4   |
|      1     |     5   |
|      2     |     3   |
|      2     |     4   |
|      2     |     2   |
|      3     |     1   |
|      3     |     2   |
|      3     |     3   |
|      3     |     5   |
|      4     |     4   |
|      4     |     2   |
+------------+---------+
```

I would like to get the average by group BUT using the first 2 elements on each group. 

Example:

```
+------------+---------+
|    MovieId |  rating  |
+------------+---------+
|      1     |     4   |
|      1     |     3   |
|      2     |     3   |
|      2     |     4   |
|      3     |     1   |
|      3     |     2   |
|      4     |     4   |
|      4     |     2   |
+------------+---------+
```

answer expected:

```
+------------+---------+
|    MovieId |  AVG    |
+------------+---------+
|      1     |     3.5 |
|      2     |     3.5 |
|      3     |     1.5 |
|      4     |     3   |
+------------+---------+
```

This is the SQL query I have to get the AVG for all of the movies. But as I said, I would like to use just the first 2 elements for each group.


`SELECT movieid, AVG(cast(rating as DECIMAL(10,2))) AS AVG
  FROM ratings
  group by movieid`

If you can help me to make the SQL I appreciate. I will also use Linq just in case some of you know it.

Comment: First two elements based on what?

Comment: just the first n elements on each group.

Answer (score 0):

In a SQL DBMS -- as in the relational model -- there is no "first".  Do you mean any arbitrary 2 rows for each movie, or the two highest ratings, or something else?

If you can't define an order, then the query is meaningless.

If you can define an order, join the table to itself as I show in my [canonical example](http://www.schemamania.org/sql/#rank.rows) to create a ranking, and select `where RANK < 3`.

Comment: I could be 2 arbitrary elements.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  As I said, the query then has *no* meaning.

Answer (score 0):

FOR Mysql:-

```
select id, avg(rating) 
from (SELECT a.*, @num := @num + 1 rownum,
        (select count(*) 
         from movies m 
         where m.id<=a.id) last_count,

        (select count(*) 
         from movies m1 
         where a.id=m1.id) grp_count 
      from movies a, (SELECT @num := 0) d) f  
where grp_count-(last_count-rownum)<=2 
group by id;
```

you can use `rownum` function in oracle. And `row_number()` function in sql server.

Answer (score -1):

This is a solution in SQL

```
Create table #tempMovie (movieId int ,rating int)

INSERT INTO #tempMovie
Select  *  from table where movieidid=1 Limit 2
Union all
Select *  from table where movieidid=2 Limit 2
Union all
Select *  from table where movieidid=3 Limit 2
Union all
Select  *  from table where movieidid=4 Limit 2
```

Temporary table #tempmovie table will contain data like this

```
+------------+---------+
|    MovieId |  rating  |
+------------+---------+
|      1     |     4   |
|      1     |     3   |
|      2     |     3   |
|      2     |     4   |
|      3     |     1   |
|      3     |     2   |
|      4     |     4   |
|      4     |     2   |
+------------+---------+
```

then apply group by

```
Select movieId, AVG(rating)
from #tempMovie
Group by movieId

Drop table #tempmovie
```

Comment: Yeah, that's one solution. But I needed dynamically, I will be working with 2000 movies records. And taking just the first 2 is one example, I will need to do avg N+1...

Comment: His question is tagged `mysql`, which doesn't have `top`.

Comment: @Barmar then `LIMIT` should be used

Comment: `LIMIT` is on the total number of rows in the result, not per-group. Mysql does not have this feature built in.

Comment: Your solution only works if you know all the movie IDs when you're creating the query, it's not a general solution.

Comment: yes this is a drawback ...

Comment: I know all the movies Id