# SQL Server get data from Openquery filtered by local query

Tags: sql-server

This is my openquery

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 'SELECT 
                                  A.Reference, 
                                  B.Ticket, B.Localization
                              FROM References AS A
                              LEFT JOIN Tickets B ON B.Reference = A.Reference')
```

I need to limit how many tickets there are per reference. I have this number in a local query

```
SELECT 
    Reference,
    QTYBoxes 
FROM 
    Supplies
```

Basically the number of tickets is equal to number of Boxes.

I need a way to join both tables and somehow say that count(tickets) = Boxes but i have no idea how can i do this on an open query.

The alternative is to get the data from OpenQuery to a temp table where i can join and limit pretty easy, the problem is that I am querying over thousand results just for this.

Here is updated query, I just need to get n tickets per reference now

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer,
       'SELECT 
             A.Reference, 
             B.Ticket, 
             B.Localization
       FROM References AS A
       LEFT JOIN Tickets B ON B.Reference = A.Reference') A
RIGHT JOIN Supplies B
ON A.Reference = B.Reference
// Must have n Tickets per reference = B.Boxes
```

**EDIT**

I forgot to add, the actual result should be X Rows per Reference ordered by Tickets Ascending

Here is an example of the intended result

```
Reference  |  Ticket   | Boxes
  M100     |    1      |   1
  M200     |    2      |   2
  M200     |    3      |   2
  M300     |    5      |   3
  M300     |    6      |   3
  M300     |    7      |   3
```

Comment: What you are asking sounds a little arbitrary. For example, if you only want 10 rows per reference, is there a way to determine which 10 rows are preferred over the rest or doesn't it matter because they all are equivalent?

Comment: Sure i forgot to add it's n rows per Reference ordered by Tickets, that should clear things up

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127646/sql-group-by-using-the-first-n-elements-in-each-group

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft

> OPENQUERY can be referenced in the FROM clause of a query as if it were a table name.

Therefore, you could write your query like this:

```
SELECT 
   S. Reference,
   S. QTYBoxes 
FROM OPENQUERY(LinkedServer, 
    'SELECT 
        A.Reference, 
        B.Ticket, B.Localization
     FROM References AS A
        LEFT JOIN Tickets B ON B.Reference = A.Reference') 
AS C --alias your openquery result like it is just another table
  INNER JOIN Supplies S ON C.Reference = S.Reference
```